# Как передать список в SQL скрипт и обработать его?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Имеется список товаров: товар1, ..., товарN. Надо в БД создать таблицы для каждого товара (несколько таблиц для каждого товара). Надо написать SQL скрипт, который будет принимать на вход список товаров и, в цикле, будет для кадого товара создавать таблицы. Что-то типо:

```
list.txt:
товар1
...
товарN

Команда:
script.sql list.txt

Результат:
в БД создана таблица всех товаров и дополнительные таблицы для каждого товара
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это сделать с помощью  SQL? Какие SQL команды смотреть? Или эту задачу вообще лучше рашать другими средствами, например, скрипт на питоне писать?

Comment: Выясните, какая у Вас СУБД (MySQL или PostgreSQL) и какой версии, и добавьте в вопрос (удалив заодно ошибочный тег). В любом случае это будет хранимая процедура.

Comment: Вы уверены, что для каждого товара вам нужна своя таблица? В 99% случаев это ошибочная логика и все товары нужно складывать в одну таблицу

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov У меня будет и таблица в которой хранятся все товары, но еще будут и отдельные таблицы для каждого товара (например история покупок конкретного товара).

Comment: @Akina Конкретная БД не принципиальна, я могу использовать и MySQL и PostgreSQL и что-либо другое. Теги удалил.

Comment: @Daniel если вам нужна история покупок для каждого товара, то вы можете создать одну таблицу "история покупок" и из неё ссылаться на справочник товаров